# TypeCode vs typeof

Tags: c#, typeof, typing

If I need some type-specific code, I could use `typeof` for example:

```
private static bool IsNumericType(Type type)
{
    return type == typeof(int) || type == typeof(decimal); //etc
}
```

But I could also use the enum [TypeCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
private static bool IsNumeric(TypeCode objTypeCode)
{
    return objTypeCode == TypeCode.Int16 || objTypeCode == TypeCode.Int32 || objTypeCode == TypeCode.Int64; // etc ||
}
```

What is the benefit of using `TypeCode` over `typeof` from an architectural and performance viewpoint? In which case should I use the one of the two?

FYI, the code to get the `type` / `typeCode` from an value:

```
var type = value.GetType();
var typeCode =  Convert.GetTypeCode(value);
```

PS: These examples are strongly simplified.

PS 2: If I pass the value, I could also use `as`, `is` etc. But In this case I don't like to send as the method doesn't need to know the value, only it's type.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the former snippet will be more performant. Basing this on the fact that `typeof()` is performed at compile-time vs. run-time. It also doesn't require the `Convert.GetTypeCode()` call. You could always benchmark it and see for yourself though!

Comment: GetTypeCode snuck in at .NET version 1.  Rather important to make a switch-statement efficient back in those dark doomy desperate days of not having generics.  That got fixed at version 2.  They even fixed the switch statement at version 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TypeCode` works best when you are following several possible paths, and most or all of the logic can be done by examining the code alone as then `switch`ing on that will be pretty efficient, and generally pretty clear.

In other cases you are likely to have as much logic inside the `Object` branch as outside since that is the code for most types, in which case it tends not to be as useful to examine the code first unless perhaps the cases that are served well by it are also cases that come up particularly often.

Your `IsNumeric` example is a good example of when `TypeCode` works well as if you rewrite it to a switch you are answering with one virtual call to get the code and one switch of the sort that compiles to relatively efficient jumps rather than branch on multiple comparisons of different possible types.

Note that enum types have the same code as their underlying numeric types. Whether that counts as having those cases covered for free, or as a case you'll have to guard against separately depends on how you want to consider those types for whatever your purpose is.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes before I answer:

1. `typeof` takes a type (NOT an instance)
2. [`IConvertible.GetTypeCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible.gettypecode?view=net-6.0#system-iconvertible-gettypecode) requires an instance that implements the `IConvertible` interface

Thus they are different. So the question you need to ask yourself is do you want the type of an instance or a type.

---

[This is from Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible.gettypecode?view=net-6.0#system-iconvertible-gettypecode):

> Call the `GetTypeCode` method on classes that implement the `IConvertible` interface to obtain the type code for an instance of that class.
> Otherwise, call an object's `GetType` method to obtain its `Type` object, then call the Type object's `GetTypeCode` method to obtain the object's type code.

Therefore, if a type does not implement `IConvertible` interface, then you need to make 2 calls: `GetType` and then call `GetTypeCode`. I also pulled the code from .NET source code for `GetTypeCode`:

```cs
    public static TypeCode GetTypeCode(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            return TypeCode.Empty;
        return type.GetTypeCodeImpl();
    }
    
    protected virtual TypeCode GetTypeCodeImpl()
    {
        // System.RuntimeType overrides GetTypeCodeInternal
        // so we can assume that this is not a runtime type
    
        // this is true for EnumBuilder but not the other System.Type subclasses in BCL
        if (this != UnderlyingSystemType && UnderlyingSystemType != null)
            return Type.GetTypeCode(UnderlyingSystemType);
        
        return TypeCode.Object;
    }
```

As you can see there is quite a bit going on there. Now without bench-marking it is hard to say but I am pretty sure since `typeof` is compile time, and it is native to C#, the team has put work into it to make it efficient. The fact that `typeof` is:

1. Native to C#
2. Decided at compile time
3. Does not depend on an interface
4. Is not 2 calls in some cases
5. It is more straight forward

I would go with `typeof`.

I always remember this rule:

First make it work. Then, only if you need to make it work faster, change it.

Comment: `GetTypeCode` does not require an instance that implements the `IConvertible` interface, you can call `Type.GetTypeCode()` on any type.

Comment: It looks like the `GetTypeCode()` extension method is only available on objects that implement `IConvertible` but you can pass any type to `Type.GetTypeCode()` method.

Comment: Just a note when it comes to passing types to `Type.GetTypeCode()`: I tried to do an implementation of the `IConvertible` interface. But whatever I chose to return in `GetTypeCode()` of that implementation the `Type.GetTypeCode(type)` always returned `Object`.